# Ruby and Golang time parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, go, time

I understand how to parse times from strings using Golang.

Currently, I make a request in rails/ruby that is handled by Go, in which I pass in a time parameter.

This is what I'm doing in rails

```
  resp = connection.get "url", {
    updated_at: updated_at
  }.compact
```

and `updated_at` is `Time.now - 1.day`.

In Go, this is how I'm parsing the time, after getting it out.

```
updatedAt, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST", updatedAtVar)
```

The above works if time looks like

```
2014-11-17 23:02:03 +0000 UTC
```

but Ruby spits out a time that looks like

```
2016-08-10 22:29:51 +0000
```

which, when parsing results in

```
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

What can I pass into my param such that go will parse the time correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format string provided in [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) contains some redundant information (MST and -0700 in particular convey the same information—a UTC offset in hours*100+minutes).

So, just leave "MST" out of your format string.

Comment: Ah thanks! I was also wondering - what if I want to get `2014-11-17 23:02:03 +0000 UTC` in Go, how would I do that?

Comment: Use `time.Format` to lay out your times as strings in the format you want, again using the sentinel value `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006` (mnemonic: 1/2 3:04:05 pm '06, -0700).

So for this case: `time.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST")`

Comment: (I kind of wish they'd gone with `2001-02-03 4:05:06 pm, -0700 MST` as their mnemonic sentinel value, but whatever.)

Comment: wait..so how do I get a time like `2014-11-17 23:02:03 +0000`?

Comment: If you want a `time.Time` variable with a value representing `2014-11-16 23:02:03 +0000`, then call `time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700", "2014-11-16 23:02:03 +0000")`.

If you already have that in some `var t time.Time`, and you want to print it as a string in that format, then call `t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700")`.